# Story Identification: Book set in Egypt with a (previously) undiscovered, upside-down pyramid

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book back in the late 90s, early 00s when I was in primary school/early high school. This is what I can remember:

- An Archaeologist, down on his luck, stumbles upon a massive open-air sandstone slab or floor near the Great Pyramids
- Everyone speculates what it is, Ancient meeting place or town square, dance floor etc.
- Bad guy takes credit (The bad guy seems to always steal his discoveries - sort of a major hero's foil)
- The hero keeps looking, and discovers a hidden tunnel. Makes it past all the booby traps, and ends up in a massive underground cavern, where the upside-down pyramid is. The 'bottom' (top) of the pyramid in this case is the sandstone 'floor' discovered previously.

I remember the Hero and the side-kick talking about how little difference their weight would make if they scale the sides, but that's about it.

Every search I do just brings up the journalism technique called the 'inverted-pyramid', and books describing the technique.

Comment: What age group was it for?

Comment: @sjl - I'm guessing young teens, don't know exactly

Comment: Can this be a story from Martin Mystere comic book ? There is Sergej Orloff as the bad guy. Other details match the vein of the comic book. But, I do not remember this exact story !

Comment: @Malkocoglu - I don't think it was a comic, Because I can't remember any panes or anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the book is probably
**"Cairo Jim and the Secret Sepulchre of the Sphinx" by Geoffrey McSkimming**, although it might possibly be another book in the same series.

I remember the upside-down buried pyramid, and the bad guy sticking all kinds of random fake columns and things on the flat 'top' of the pyramid to try and pass off the site as something else.  I kept a reading log years ago, and between that and my memory I dredged up that title as being the most likely candidate.

[The Cairo Jim website](http://www.cairojim.com/chronicles) description for that book also makes it seem likely:

> When that well-known archaeologist and little-known poet, Cairo Jim,
>   and his friends Doris the macaw and Brenda the Wonder Camel, and
>   Jocelyn Osgood make the ‘find of the century’, a new enemy on the
>   scene sets out to discredit Jim and destroy his hard-won reputation …

Comment: That's it! Wow thank you!